# com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory; missing in Google Drive example

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I tried running the [quickstart-sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java), and this dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
<version>v2-rev78-1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

from [Drive wiki API page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API)

Yet when I try to compile the code `com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;` is missing.
To verify this you just need to do Step 2 & 3! Where can I find this class or how can I replace it in the sample?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Jackson library can be found 
at http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson/

For July 7, last version can be obtained by Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

You may also need

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For those needing Jackson2, simply replace `jackson` with `jackson2` above.

Comment: Gradle line :P `compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.15.0-rc'`

Comment: `JacksonFactory` has been deprecated, use `com.google.api.client.json.GsonFactory` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Use this class for JacksonFactory instead of the previous one.

com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.11, jackson library has been moved out to separate jar to provide developers better choice of versions of each library. Please check readme.html of zip file you downloaded from google-api-java-client and you can check which specific jar file you want to include in your project.

Answer (score 1):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.client/google-api-client/1.4.1-beta

This dependency will solve your problem:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
<version>1.4.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For gradle.build =

```
compile group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-jackson2', version: '1.11.0-beta'
```