# Cannot resolve import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, google-api-java-client

Am trying to use the `GsonFactory` class in my app:

```
StudentApi.Builder builder = new StudentApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
```

but it says `cannot resolve symbol 'GsonFactory'`

I have the import in my class

```
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
```

but `gson` couldn't be resolved so I tried `Alt-Enter - Find jar on web` but the library couldn't be found.

I have this in my `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
   compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0'
}
```

I can confirm that this class does [exist](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/google-http-client-gson/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/json/gson/GsonFactory.java?r=419710e80d2fa74c6b2f1311e5151495890732c8).

Comment: You can also use JacksonFactory if possible.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231722/com-google-api-client-json-jackson-jacksonfactory-missing-in-google-drive-examp

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use this library:

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
```

Comment: You can also use JacksonFactory() in lieu of GsonFactory for those API builders if there is some trouble with the dependency.

Comment: One more comment: For some reason if using the maven dependency doesn't download the Gson library -- you can just include the library manually. http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-gson/1.19.0/google-api-client-gson-1.19.0.jar

Answer (score 9):

GsonFactory is from the older version.

Now, you should use `JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()` instead.

Import it like this `import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;`

Answer (score 4):

As of 2022, `GsonFactory` is back and `JacksonFactory` is deprecated. Replace `JacksonFactory` with `GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()`.

In Gradle: use

```
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.41.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your gradle.build you need to add:

```
compile ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

after

```
compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.19.0') {
    exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
}
```

After doing so, you will be able to use:

```
com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory()
```

Answer (score 0):

this object is only in older versions of the google-http-client try whit the 1.9.0-beta version

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.9.0-beta'
```