# ClassNotFoundException jackson.core.JsonFactory

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

**Hi all,
I was trying to write files to my Google Drive. But when I run my app it says**

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:44)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory$InstanceHolder.<clinit>(JacksonFactory.java:64)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(JacksonFactory.java:59)
    at com.example.googleAPI.GoogleDriveStart.<clinit>(GoogleDriveStart.java:24)`
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 4 more`

**I've tried to change my Json-core version in gradle to the newest one, also tried to lower my springboot version.**

here is my gradle snippet 

    `compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.11.0.rc1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.11.0.rc1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.0'`

**I've been spinning around with this for hours, any suggestions where it went wrong ?**

Comment: you want to try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17512552/4828463

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just gave it a go but it does not work @Faraz

Comment: Take a look at [drive-cmdline-sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/drive-cmdline-sample). You should not add `Jackson` libraries directly to your dependencies.